# Does free fall in a magnetic field also leads to no force acting on the falling object similar to free fall in gravity

Tags: electromagnetism, newtonian-gravity

In complete absence of gravity if a metallic object free falls in a magnetic field will it continuously feel the force of magnetic field or will stop feeling the magnetic field during the free fall.

Comment: What's going to cause it to "fall" in the absence of gravity?

Comment: What's your magnetic field? If velocity of particle and mangetic fields are parallel then no force will be applied to the particle.

Comment: "Free fall" doesn't _lead_ to no force acting on the falling object. "Free fall" is our _name_ for the condition of no force acting on the object.

Answer (score 0):

The term "falling" really has no well defined meaning in the absence of gravity. The object will feel the force of the magnetic field as long as it's inside the magnetic field and it will accelerate accordingly. Eventually the object will either move out of the field or just bump into one of the poles.